# MySQL Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've spend hours on this problem and I'm going mad. I just can't find any logic in it at all. 

http://1.1m.yt/DZQnw5ZtV.png

The following mysqli query;

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_name, user_hash, user_signup_date, game_accounts) VALUES (NULL , 'bob', 'bob', '2000/1/1', 'derp')";
mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Gives the following error;

> Unknown column 'game_accounts' in 'field list'

However the weird part is that when I execute the following command in MySQL Database Console;

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_name, user_hash, user_signup_date, game_accounts) VALUES (NULL , 'bob', 'bob', '2000/1/1', 'derp');
```

It works just fine..

http://3.1m.yt/IEje4Zr_i.png

Any ideas on this problem are greatly appreciated.

NOTE: The connection to the db is fine. All other queries work correctly.

**UPDATE: ^apparently not. The db worked fine, the wrong db that is..**

Comment: Are you sure your connections are to the same servers/schema?

Comment: @uueerdo all other queries work just fine so I suppose it's safe to say they are.

Comment: Was it renamed possibly? I'd suggest deleting the column and re-adding it.

Comment: Well, what does `SHOW columns FROM users` say if you add it to your PHP code?

Comment: @nintender I tried, I deleted the whole table and added them all over again to no avail..

Comment: Try removing `user_id` and its value `NULL` from the query.

Comment: make sure you didn't accidentally pushed the spacebar when you created that column

Comment: @alexander-obersht In the MySQL console it returns [Screen](http://2.1m.yt/CoOmDGdZ.png) and in php it returns [Screen](http://1.1m.yt/MyR0NFfta.png)

Comment: plus, your `user_id` column doesn't seem to accept NULL, so instead of `VALUES (NULL ,` do `VALUES ('',`

Comment: As it explicitly complains about that one particular column beeing wrong, I assume al other possible errors as of the above comments are not applicable. One thing I know from own experience: **Possibly the wrong Database** ?

Comment: I thought of that too ^

Comment: The first above-comment says it, OP said other queries work fine.

Comment: @AlanMachado if OP connects to other database schema that has almost all same tables it is possible that it looks like connection is OK, but connection is linked to the wrong DB.

Comment: [If SHOW COLUMNS returned nothing](http://1.1m.yt/MyR0NFfta.png), then your connection is wrong!

Comment: @AlanMachado As a mater of experience, during development you ave gazllions of copies of your DB, probably accessing an older one where this column is actually missing. And obviously not doing that error @ the console.

Comment: A shot in the dark: temporary table getting in the way of permanent one with the same name?

Comment: @AlexanderObersht I see...

Comment: @fred-ii replacing NULL with '' only seems to make things worse since its A_I it doesn't accept strings. [screen](http://3.1m.yt/upsl2Q9vH.png)

Comment: Show us proof please. do screenshot from phpMyAdmin where we can see database schema as well as table structure on the same view, and provide your php mysql connection fragment of code

Comment: *Shooting myself in the foot...* - ouch. Ok, my bad

Comment: @Fred-ii- ... means what?

Comment: @AxelAmthor about using `VALUES ('',` rather than `VALUES (NULL,`

Comment: If ther would be a prob with the values, there would be a different error message. It's not about the values provided, we aren't that far ;-)

Comment: *however it won't put the data into the db* - Because you are connected to the wrong database schema!

Comment: As a proof: drop any other column, '**don't change your PHP** and run it again. If it's **not complaining now**  you're on the wrong scheme!

Comment: @alex Couldn't check all comments at same time so I was still checking previous replies haha. You were right, it was connection to the wrong database. The funny part however was that all other queries were still working just fine so I didn't notice it.

Comment: I'm too long in that business ...

Comment: About that *"shooting in the foot"* bit ;-)

Comment: @axel-amthor post it as answer and so I can accept it as answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i prefer *Take a break for a coffee cup*, it is more peaceful :-) and it helps better than shoot :-D

Comment: @Alex - *Aye,* indeed. I'll have an "espresso" or "cappuccino" *per me, grazie!* - ciao.

Comment: @uueerdo oh wait, my bad, you were the first one to point out the possibility that its the wrong db. Post it as answer and I'll pick you as answer :)

Comment: the upvote  belongs to @Uueerdo, honestly

Comment: @shadryck appears to be that the very first comment was sufficient for you to realize this basic mistake but still you kept claiming that it was the right schema. You even put that claim into an edit of your question and now you're saying that you didn't read any comments.

Comment: @ejay The db was a backup of the current db so all other queries were working just fine. Also I only said that the connection to the db was just fine, not that the database wasn't the problem. No need to be all uptight about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When developing against test databases (always a good practice), if a relatively simple query you know should work doesn't, make sure you are looking at the right database.

Comment: Yikes, this should be tagged under "Is it plugged in" kind of answer. Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.
Please replace yourDBNameHere by your actual database name, try the following code (after checking that it doesn't do something malicious, of course) and add the output to your question text.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_name, user_hash, user_signup_date, game_accounts) VALUES (NULL , 'bob', 'bob', '2000/1/1', 'derp')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if (!$result ) {
    $query = "
        SELECT
            COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE
            table_name = 'users'
            AND table_schema = 'yourDBNameHere'
    ";
    $result = $con->query($query) or die('my my my');
    while( $row=$result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        if ( false!==strpos($row['COLUMN_NAME'], 'game') ) {
            var_export($row);
        }
        else {
            echo join(', ', $row), "\r\n";
        }
    }
}
```